# compiling component scss files angular

Tags: angular, sass

so i wanted to use scss for my angular 4 project, i configured it with angular-cli config file, and everything is working, except one thing:

in my main style.scss file i import bootstrap variables file

```
@import './assets/styles/bootstrap/_variables.scss';
@import './assets/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss';

@import "./assets/styles/datepicker.scss";
@import "./assets/styles/select2.scss";
```

i have a variable `$gray-me` defined in _`_variables.scss` file.

when i want to use this variable in the `style.scss` file, it work as excpected, but when i want to use it in a compoenent scss file, it give me this errorr

`Undefined variable: "$gray-me"`

its like the component scss and global style.scss where compiled separatly.

so is there is a way to fix that and make them compile in one piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you `@import` all required .scss files in your component.scss. The component.scss files are not global and therefore need to explicitly import all required references, i.e. `@import "__variables"`.